# Consume online API in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-template, web-api-testing

I am learning Angular and trying to consume an online web API in which I have app.module.ts, a service file, a model named comments, app.component.ts and app.component.html files
I am trying to show posts in my browser from the online web API from  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments URL.

My code compiles successfully, but doesn't show any data in the browser and I can't find any errors. I am working in Angular 8/9. My code is below.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FreeapiService } from './services/freeapi.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [FreeapiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**freeapi.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FreeapiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getComments(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
  }
}
```

**Comments Class**

```
export class Comments {
  postId: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  body: string;
}
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FreeapiService } from './services/freeapi.service';
import { Comments } from './classes/comments';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-apicall';
  constructor(private _freeApiService: FreeapiService) { }
  istComments: Comments[];
  ngOnInt() {
    this._freeApiService.getComments()
      .subscribe
      (
        data => {
          this.istComments = data;
        }
      );
    console.log("This is working");
  }
}
```

This my **app.component.html** file in which I want to show data in a table, but only show header

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Post Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Body</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let com of istComments">
    <td>{{com.id}}</td>
    <td>{{com.postId}}</td>
    <td>{{com.name}}</td>
    <td>{{com.email}}</td>`enter code here`
    <td>{{com.body]}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You've made a typo - `ngOnInt` instead of `ngOnInit`

Comment: And the `AppComponent` should implement the `OnInit` inteface. See an example here: https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit#usage-notes

Comment: @tenkmilan That's not strictly necessary, but it does help avoid bugs like this

Comment: @KurtHamilton Dear sir  i change ngOnInt to ngOnInit then it working Thanks a lot.